# How to get form inside of image to resize correctly on twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using a responsive wordpress theme that is based on twitter bootstrap. For some reason the side bar images aren't resizing correctly. (You can see what I mean by checking out the [site][1] and trying to resize.) I was approaching this by declaring a fixed size to the widget, and then positioning the form inside it using absolutely relative positioning. The image / contact form looks fine when you are on a desk top but as you compress the layout (for instance on an iphone) the contact form and image do not resize correctly. I'm not sure where to go from here and sort of stuck.

Here's the css I'm using now (which may not be correct.) Thanks!

```
.widget .signupForm {
    /* Box always has colour, pic always on right */
    background-color: #06d0d2;
    background-image: url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/noahs-dad-side-bar.jpg);
    background-position: right bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    /* height ensures full pic is shown  */
    height: 300px;    

    /* allow us to position contents */
    position: relative;
}

/* Absolutely position the form within the widget */
.widget .signupForm form {
 position: absolute;
 right: 160px;  
 bottom: 0px;
}

.widget .signupForm form input {
 display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {


/* now just resize the widget box and move the form */

.widget .signupForm {
 width: 300px; 
 height: 240px;
 background-size: 100%;    
}

    .widget .signupForm form {
        right: 120px;   
        bottom: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: you want your side bar to remain as a side bar?.. now,its coming below the content.. what is your expected result on resize?

Comment: No. I want things to resize correctly. For instance the first image does not stay resized correctly when it goes below the content area. It changes from a square to a rectangle.

Comment: @VivekChandra Just wanted to follow up to see if you had any other ideas on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can detect 3 problems at a width of 800px:

- `.widget .signupForm` has a width of 300px. It should be `auto` or `100%`. Then form elements are to be sized accordingly, if needed (btw the submit button has same text and background than the text input. It seems we have 2 informations to type when in fact it's the action button. It doesn't need to be white on blue, maybe a darker grey would be sufficient. I'm not a designer, though ;) )
- Facebook widget has a fixed width. Does it exist a mobile version of this widget?
- same problem with the Instagram one: images have an HTML width attribute of 300 (pixels).

Comment: Thanks. I tried to add the 100% and it didn't work. The images still didn't resize correctly.  Also If you resize to where the side bar goes into the content area, you'll more issues. Also, right before the side bar goes under the content area you'll notice the small images at the bottom of the page aren't resizing well either. (The one that is for reeces rainbow and the clothing company image.) Here is a jfiddle where it was resizing correctly, but it doesn't work like this in my theme. Trying to figure out what I'm missing. http://jsfiddle.net/andrewheins/9PrG2/5/

Comment: did you have any other ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

The Following css applies to your page when it gets resized. Not sure which file is applying it.Find this class in your css files and add a width to it, say `width:300px` if you want it to be a perfect square or any other value.

```
.widget .signupForm {
    background-color: #06D0D2;
    background-image: url("http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/noahs-dad-side-bar.jpg");
    background-position: right bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 300px;
    width:300px; /* code added here */
    position: relative;
}
```

Hope it helps,if i havnt understood ur problem or this is not the solution you were looking for - do comment..